# Pandoc: no line wrapping when converting to HTML

Tags: word-wrap, pandoc

I am converting from Markdown to HTML like so:

`pandoc --columns=70 --mathjax -f markdown input.pdc -t html -Ss > out.html`

Everything works fine, except for the fact that the text doesn't get wrapped. I tried different columns lengths, no effect. Removed options, no go. Whatever I tried, the HTML just doesn't get wrapped. I search the bug tracker, but there don't seem to be any open bugs relating to this issue. I also checked the documentation, but as far as I could glean, the text ought be line-wrapped... So, have I stumbled into a bug?

I'm using pandoc version 1.12.4.2.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pandoc puts newlines in the HTML so the source code is easier to read. By default, it doesn't insert `<br>`-tags.

If you want to preserve line breaks from markdown input:

```
pandoc -f markdown+hard_line_breaks input.md output.html
```

However, usually a better approach to limit the text width when opening the HTML file in the browser is to adapt the HTML [template](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#templates) (`pandoc -D html5`) and add some CSS, like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html$if(lang)$ lang="$lang$"$endif$>
<head>
  <style>
  body {
     width: 46em;
  }
  </style>
...
```

Comment: With a tremendous apology for the delay, if that is the case, then I again ask: what is the `--columns` option good for??

Comment: The `--columns` option specifies how many characters are on a line of source code. In [HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs), linebreaks in the sourcecode don't affect how the text is displayed in the browser. Instead, you could use `<br>` tags to put linebreaks, but it's better to use CSS to describe how the content is displayed (as I did in my answer inside the `style` tags). See for example http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/web

Comment: (open the resulting HTML file in a plain text editor like Sublime to see the effect of different `--columns` options)

Comment: OK that explains it... but still that's not how I would interpret pandoc's [README](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html) ...

Answer (score 5):

It is not clear what text should get wrapped but does not as you did not provide a sample.

Pandoc supports several line breaking scenarios in markdown documents.

What you may be looking for is the [hard_line_breaks extension](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#non-pandoc-extensions)

If it is so then your command should look like

`pandoc --columns=70 --mathjax -f markdown+hard_line_breaks input.pdc -t html -Ss > out.html`

I'd recommend you to read about all the markdown-relevant options and configure pandoc to match your input markdown flavor

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, it was helpful, but not quite what I was looking for. What that does is put in the HTML the *same* line breaks that exist in the markdown original. Which means it ignores the `--columns` value. Is there way to actually wrap the text to the desired line length, or is the `--columns` setting simply not supposed to be used with HTML?

Comment: @wmnorth I don't know how the ```columns``` is supposed to work and what exactly you'd like to achieve. If you want to get a 70*[em](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) wide HTML paragraph then you can achieve it by CSS applied to your HTML document. Also there are some special presentation-style rules that influence word breaking and line breaking and cause the document reflow in the HTML renderer, e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp

Comment: If you really want to wrap output at 70 *source* chars, you could first run `pandoc --columns=70 -f markdown -t markdown` and pipe that into `pandoc -f markdown+hard_line_breaks`, but that's really wrong (and will look ugly).  The purpose of `hard_line_breaks` is to preserve *semantic* line breaks, such as in verse; simply wrapping output to fit the screen (or a narrower column) should be left to the browser/CSS.