# pandoc .md to .docx conversion: preserving original linebreaks

Tags: pandoc

I'm converting a simple markdown file to docx. I would like the output not to wrap lines.

My impression from the documentation is that `--wrap=none` will do this, but the docx output still wraps lines not separated by a blank line. I prefer not to wrap the file content with "~~~" lines.

Is there another switch I'm missing?

mb21 suggests that my questions is a duplicate of [Pandoc: no line wrapping when converting to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469694/pandoc-no-line-wrapping-when-converting-to-html). It isn't quite a duplicate, since that issue addresses how to get lines to break in a controlled way rather than how to preserve the original line breaks. However, the answers in that thread mentions the "-f markdown+hard_line_breaks option", which DOES solve my issue. Thanks to mb21!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandoc: no line wrapping when converting to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469694/pandoc-no-line-wrapping-when-converting-to-html)

Comment: Do you want to add the answer as an answer and accept it? That said, that doesn't solve my problem, which is that I want empty lines between paragraphs.